# command to rename a KDE session in tcsh on Solaris system?

Tags: solaris, tcsh, kde-plasma

I want to rename the shell session. The obvious way is to right click on the tab and select "Rename Session...". But I want to do it in a script.

I am using KDE3.5.10, tcsh on Solaris OS. I tried below two methods, and both not working for me.

1. `dcop $KONSOLE_DCOP_SESSION renameSession "NEW NAME"`
   (in this case, I got error saying "dcop" is not a recognized command)
2. `echo -en "\e]30;NEW NAME\a"`
   (this would just echo back the string enclosed).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change konsole tab title from command line and make it persistent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19897787/change-konsole-tab-title-from-command-line-and-make-it-persistent)

Comment: FWIW that solution works for me in gnome too. http://superuser.com/questions/705898/set-name-of-konsole-window might have additional solutions as well.